# Turn off the effect that the space between words are expanded to fit the columns

Tags: spacing, sciposter

Currently I have the my draft of poster as below:

```
\documentclass[a2]{sciposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/asus_user/Pictures/} }

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/asus_user/Pictures/} }

\title{The Structure of Groups with Given Absolute Central Factor Group}

\institute 
{Institute of Mathematical Sciences\\
    University of Malaya\\
    50603 Kuala Lumpur}

\email{alanwang@siswa.um.edu.my}

\rightlogo[1]{um}

\begin{document}
    
\conference{{\bf SJEM3380 Mathematical Science Project}, Semester 2 Session 2015/2016}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}
\section{Definition}
The following are definitions of main terms used in the project.

\begin{Def}
    The \textbf{Frattini subgroup} of a group $G$, denoted by $\Phi(G)$ is the intersection of all subgroups $M\leq G$, where $M$ is maximal in $G$.
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
    A group $G$ is said to be \textbf{capable} if there exists a group $H$ such that $H/Z(H)\cong G$.
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
    A \textbf{autocommutator subgroup} is defined as
    \begin{equation*}
    K(G)=\langle g^{-1}g^\alpha:g\in G,\alpha\in \textrm{Aut}(G)\rangle
    \end{equation*}
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
    The \textbf{absolute center} of autocommutator subgroup is defined as 
    \begin{equation*}
    L(G)=\{g\in G:g^\alpha = g,\forall \alpha\in \textrm{Aut}(G)\}
    \end{equation*} 
\end{Def}   

\section{Introduction}
In recent years much progress has been made in the study of groups whose central quotient groups are abelian. Such a group is an extension of an abelian group by an abelian group. The study of capable groups plays a central role in various group theoretical problems. \\
Baer \cite{Baer} was the first who studied the structure of capable groups in detail and classified all finite capable groups. He characterized those groups whose central contains a given abelian group and whose quotient group is isomorphic to preassigned abelian group .\\

\section{Objectives}

\section{Previous Results}  
    
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Then, in the Definition 3, the space between the words A autocommutator subgroup is expanded.
How can I turn off this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default LaTeX alignment is full justification (text fills the line all the way to the margin, both left and right).  The macro `\raggedright` allows for the right margin to be ragged.  There is also a package `ragged2e` that does this and more, for the seriously ragged author.  In your case, `\raggedright` could be added just to Definition 3, to limit its scope to just that definition.  All else would remain fully justified:

```
\begin{Def}\raggedright
    An \textbf{autocommutator subgroup} is defined as
    \begin{equation*}
    K(G)=\langle g^{-1}g^\alpha:g\in G,\alpha\in \textrm{Aut}(G)\rangle
    \end{equation*}
\end{Def}
```

[image]

On the other hand, one could add `\raggedright` to the beginning of the document

```
\begin{document}
\raggedright
```

and the whole document would be created with ragged right columns:

[image]

The "ragged" macros `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` also come in environment form, `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}` and `\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}`, respectively.  These environments are useful for limiting the scope of raggedness to the enclosed text.